# How to get a value from another sql table and show it in jinja?

Tags: python, mysql

this is my users table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    karma INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci';
```

and this is how I get my comments in flask:

```
class comments():
    def gettcomm(id):
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("""
            SELECT  UserComment.*, (COUNT(Ghost.id) - 1) AS depth
            FROM (comments AS UserComment, comments as Ghost)

            WHERE   UserComment.lft BETWEEN Ghost.lft AND Ghost.rgt
            AND     Ghost.post_id = %s
            AND     UserComment.post_id =%s
            AND     UserComment.parent_id is not null

            GROUP BY UserComment.id
            ORDER BY UserComment.lft""", ([id], [id]))
        commentaria = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return commentaria

commentaria = comments.gettcomm(id)
```

I want to get the karma from the user table for every user and show it like this:

```
{% for item in commentaria %} 
            {{item['username']}} 's karma is: {{item['karma']}}
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to join both tables SQL-side like this:

```
SELECT UserComment.*, karma, (COUNT(Ghost.id) - 1) AS depth
FROM (comments AS UserComment, comments as Ghost)
JOIN users ON users.id = UserComment.user_id
WHERE UserComment.lft BETWEEN Ghost.lft AND Ghost.rgt
  AND Ghost.post_id = %s
  AND UserComment.post_id = %s
  AND UserComment.parent_id is not null
GROUP BY UserComment.id
ORDER BY UserComment.lft
```

However I can only guess the existence and name of the `user_id` field.

I would probably write it like this though:

```
SELECT UserComment.*, karma, (COUNT(Ghost.id) - 1) AS depth
FROM comments AS UserComment
JOIN comments AS Ghost ON UserComment.lft BETWEEN Ghost.lft AND Ghost.rgt
JOIN users ON users.id = UserComment.user_id
WHERE Ghost.post_id = %s
  AND UserComment.post_id = %s
  AND UserComment.parent_id is not null
GROUP BY UserComment.id
ORDER BY UserComment.lft
```